# jQuery how to destroy draggable with clone()

Tags: jquery, clone, draggable

```
$('div').draggable();
var x = $('#container').clone().find('div').draggable('destroy').end().html();
$('#save').val(x);
```

How do i destroy `draggable()` after we use clone. The html still contains the class `.ui-draggable` after destroying. Why is this happening and how can i work around it without having to to use  `removeClass()`. destroy should handle this.
Check http://jsfiddle.net/rzfPP/50/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning `.draggable()` to the newly cloned divs and then immediately destroying those seems to do the trick:

```
$('div').draggable();
var x = $('#container').clone().find('div').draggable().draggable('destroy').end().html();
$('#save').val(x);
```